# Mulesoft/Cloudhub - How do I get output from a Java class to show up in the log?

Tags: logging, mule, invoke, mule-studio

The title says it all...

I have a Mulesoft Application that is deployed to cloudhub (but the issue is the same for running locally/on-prem).  My application has a Java Invoke component that calls a method in my Java class.

The method contains output statements, such as System.out and System.err.  If I run my app in Anypoint Studio, this output shows up in the console as expected... But it doesn't show up in the log file (locally, or on cloudhub).

How do I get output from my Java class to show up in the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected ... System.out are not printed in logs should not be used in prod environment...
You need to use log4j2.xml in your `src/main/resource` folder and need to use `org.apache.logging.log4j` in your Java class.

An example:-

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4j2Tester {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Log4j2Tester.class);

    public String test(String args) {
        LOG.error("testing ERROR level");

        LOG.info("testing INFO level");
        LOG.trace("exiting application");
        return "Done";
    }
}
```

For more ref:- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html
For Cloudhub custom log appender :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/custom-log-appender

Comment: Thanks Anirban, I completely forgot that Log4j was being used for log generation.